# Unable to start app server in Netbeans

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, ide, glassfish

I am unable to run either Tomcat (Version 7), or Glassfish (Version 4.1.1) in Netbeans.

I have tried re-installing the app servers and the IDE. Tried with Netbeans 8.0.2 and 8.1. It was working a few days ago.

When I run a project, the process takes a long time (>10 mins) and fails.From the Glassfish log, I see the below errors being shown commonly.

```
[2016-06-07T18:00:33.360+0530] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=112 _ThreadName=pool-22-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1465302633360] [levelValue: 1000] [[
Config Listener class com.sun.enterprise.web.reconfig.WebConfigListener notification took too long
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
at org.jvnet.hk2.config.Transactions$ConfigListenerNotifier$1.call(Transactions.java:289)
at org.jvnet.hk2.config.Transactions$ConfigListenerNotifier$1.call(Transactions.java:268)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at org.jvnet.hk2.config.Transactions$Notifier$1$1.run(Transactions.java:167)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
]]
```

Need your help in figuring out how to fix this. Thank you!

Comment: I tried using tomcat 8, which is also not working. Halp!